# sscanf On A Multi-Line File

Tags: c

I'm building a program that reads in a file and then stores each line in an array for manipulation. The input file has a single string on each line, and I want to store each read word in its own slot in a single array. This in an example input file:

```
This
is
a
test
file
```

I'm trying to use this with the kernel level read command. This is what I got:

```
const int recordSize = 1024;
char buffer [recordSize];
int n = 0;
char word[10][50];

while ((n = read(fd_in, buffer, recordSize)) > 0) {        
    sscanf(buffer,"%s\n%s",word[0],word[1]);
}
```

The file is read in and stored in buffer. Then I want to put each line into the word array. I made it to hold 10 words of 50 characters length. The purpose of doing something like this is so that I can do something like, change word[0] in one way and alter word[3] in another way.

What I tried is using sscanf. The only issue is that in order for it to know to read on to the next line, I need to use \n and another %s. Since I don't know how long the input file it, this isn't a viable solution.

Right now I'm stuck on how to nondeterministically read line 1, store it in array slot 0, and move on to the next line, repeating for line 2 and slot 1, etc.

Comment: Use something more appropriate such as `getline` (if available on your system) or `fgets` which are specifically designed to read a single line of input.

Comment: `how to nondeterministically read line 1` Read 1 byte. Is it a newline? No - store it in an array. Yes, it's a newline - you just read one line, move to the next "array slot". Repeat. But anyway, if there's no specific need to file descriptors, use `FILE*` operations.

Comment: Here's an example that reads each line of a file into an array: https://github.com/wrp/examples/blob/main/c/read-txt-into-array.c

Comment: `fscanf`?! https://linux.die.net/man/3/fscanf